# Error when running Rails Server on a local copy: Could not find mysql2-0.2.6 in any of the sources. Try running `bundle install`

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, github

I just forked a copy of an app on github and saved it on my computer. When I attempt to run the rails server in the application directory, I get the following error:

```
Could not find mysql2-0.2.6 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
```

Earlier today, however, I installed MySQL 5.1.53 for Mac OS X and supposedly installed it...at least I'm quite certain I did.

Why does terminal come up with this error message even though I'm quite certain I have MySQL already installed on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not complaining about MySQL itself, it's complaining about the missing gem.

Just do what the message says, run a `bundle install` to download and install the gem.

Comment: Yes, important to realise there's a difference between MySQL, and the Ruby code which is built to interact with MySQL

Comment: Thanks everyone! Apparently I had downloaded MySQL but somehow didn't manage to install it :| it works now.